# Use gsutil commands in R through system() -- which environmental variables do I need do assign?

Tags: r, bash, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

Not sure how I should be going about this, but it is not working currently:

My first thought: in my home directory, I have the folder for GC SDK:

```
Sys.setenv(PATH="$HOME/google-cloud-sdk")
system(paste0("gsutil cp ",paste0(bucket,cancer.id,"/rnaseq_fpkm_*.csv "),paste0(cancer.id,"/rnaseq_fpkm_*.csv")),intern=F)

sh: 1: gsutil: not found
Warning message:
In system(paste0("gsutil cp ", paste0(bucket, cancer.id, "/rnaseq_fpkm_*.csv "),  :
  error in running command
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For one thing, you basically never want to have a single-entry PATH. Setting `PATH=$HOME/google-cloud-sdk` means you no longer have `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, or the other default entries. And someone who knows R should chime in on whether the `$HOME` in your `setenv` gets expanded.

Comment: ...what I mean by "expanded" is that when in bash you run something like `PATH=$HOME/google-cloud-sdk:$PATH`, what's _actually_ assigned is something more like `PATH=/home/rebecca/google-cloud-sdk:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` (and again, the `:$PATH` on the example above is something you almost certainly want; a PATH without `/usr/bin` prevents you from running almost any of your OS vendor's provided tools). When you call `setenv` through a non-shell language, you're typically required to make those expansions (replacing `$HOME` with your real home directory, etc) happen yourself.

Comment: There are other issues here, albeit less critical -- generally, using `system()` with a non-constant string is a bad idea in any language, because everything's concatenated into a big string that's then evaluated as code by a shell; using the `execv` OS interface -- and whatever wrappers around it R has to offer -- means you need to do more work (like glob expansion) yourself, but it means you no longer need to worry about a bucket id containing `$(rm -rf ~)` in its name deleting your home directory.

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy, thanks for your response here. Admittedly, I'm not following the last bit. Are you suggesting another method of interacting with the terminal? Searching "execv in R" doesn't really yield any hits. Apologies, my knowledge in this realm is very limited.

Comment: I think the equivalent of what Charles is talking about in R would be the `system2()` function where you pass all the arguments to your program as a vector of values that will be property escaped when calling the requested program.

Comment: @MrFlick, ...at least in the UNIX world, execv (which I'd hope `system2` would be implemented with) is even better than a guarantee of "proper escaping" -- it uses an interface where the syscall used to request that the kernel execute the other software is passed a precise list of literal, NUL-terminated strings, so there's no escaping needed at all. The most bug-free escaping implementation, after all, is the one that doesn't need to exist. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add to your path rather than replace, the `withr::with_path` gives a good short term solution. You can also use `expand.path` to expand user paths to full paths. Try

```r
withr::with_path( path.expand("~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/"), {
   system(paste0("gsutil cp ",paste0(bucket,cancer.id,"/rnaseq_fpkm_*.csv "),paste0(cancer.id,"/rnaseq_fpkm_*.csv")),intern=F)
})
```

Or even just to check that it works, try

```r
withr::with_path( path.expand("~/google-cloud-sdk/bin/"), {
   print(Sys.getenv("PATH"))
   print(Sys.which("gsutil"))
})
```

Comment: Hi @MrFlick -- unfortunately R still seems unable to find the 'gsutil' command. EDIT: Oops! Just needed to add /bin to the the path -- thank you for your help!